# dotnet restore on linux does not include XML file from nuget package

Tags: linux, msbuild, nuget, dotnet-restore

I have a Visual Studio solution and am trying to build to run on a Linux installation of Docker.  As part of the process I need to copy the XML documentation from one of the nuget packages for my Swagger documentation.  On my windows development box, I am able to do this, but on Linux it is not working.  The problem seems to be when I look at the lib folder for the nuget package on linux I see only a .dll while on Windows I see both .dll and .xml.  Below is my restore command

```
RUN dotnet restore "src/Management/Management.csproj"
```

Why is the XML file not being extracted on linux?

On another note it seems like linux creates the directories using all lower case.  So if I am extracting nuget package Test.MyPackage-3.4.3 it will be located on linux at /root/.nuget/.../test.mypackage/3.4.3.  In my csproj file I am referencing the package using `%(PackageReference.Identity)` which returns the camel-case capitalization.  Is there a work-around for this as well?

Comment: NuGet should extract all files from the nupkg on all OSs, so my best guess is that there are two copies of the package with the same version on different nuget sources, one with xml and one without. Is the package public, so you can point us to it and we can take a look for ourselves?

Comment: I am working with a non-public package but made changes to do the same with Microsoft.AspNetcore.Mvc.Version v3.1.6 and see the same results.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's still a relevant question.

There is an Env variable `NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE` which is set to `skip` in Docker image provided by Microsoft.

If you change it to `ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=none` in your Dockerfile it will fix the issue. However image build time will definitely increase so you can consider having `dotnet restore` as a separate step to enable caching.

More info can be found here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-environment-variables